# How can I determine which events are attached to an element, and which functions those events trigger?

Tags: javascript, events

Is there a simple way to check with the Webkit inspector? If not, what are some other options? I'm mostly interested in finding the functions the events are triggering.

Answer (score 0):

Select the elements tab, and use the selector to select an element, on the right hand side, scroll down and select "Event Listeners"

Comment: I see that shows me which listeners are attached, but how do I find the functions those listeners call?